# Using Yammer discussions instead of the built-in sharepoint commenting feature

Tags: office-365, modern-pages, yammer, comments, yammer-embed

We want to start our new sharepoint intranet site, and we will be relying on creating modern pages and chatting capabilities. so we are going to appraoch these as follow:-

1. We will be creating SharePoint modern pages to publish articles and information and official company news.
2. We will create a Yammer group and embed it inside our SharePoint home page using the "Conversation" modern web part, to provide a company wide discussion board.
3. Now we are facing an issue on how we should implement the commenting on modern pages. as the built-in commenting provided inside sharepoint modern pages have many limitations such as; anyone can delete any comment, most of the third parties tools do not support backup-ing or migrating modern pages comments, also deleted comments can not be restored.

so to provide more robust appraoch for commenting on modern pages, we are planning to do the following:-

1. Create a modern page let say named "Test Hr Policy.aspx" >> then we will create a new yammer post >> inside the yammer post will add a Topic named "Test Hr Policy" (similar to the modern page name):-
   [image]
2. Then we will edit the modern page and add a new modern Conversation web part >> filter the conversation based on the unique topic:-
   [image]

So in this case we can benefit from sharepoint modern pages capabilities in building modern web pages + the capabilities which Yammer provide for building a robust discussion/chatting module for our pages.

so can anyone advice on the appraoch we are planning to follow; mainly on replacing the built-in sharepoint modern page's commenting sections with yammer posts (which will be linked to the modern pages using unique Topics)?

Comment: @Gautam Sheth strange why this is been put on hold,, without giving valid easons? it is not opinion based but rather a question about the limitation in SharePoint commenting and replacing this with yammer..

Comment: @Robert Lindgren is it really opinion-based? i described a problem in SP commenting and suggesting an alternative, then asking about my workaround if it is valid or not..

Comment: @Gaurravs so this question got one vote up + one reply ,, and it is a reasonable question with full details ,, not sure why it is been put on hold?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Yammer webpart on modern pages allows you to configure a Yammer group so, users can add comments to the updates and also create new updates. In other words, you have the whole functionality of a Yammer group inside a modern page. In addition to this, you should set off the comments on the SharePoint page so users will not be annoyed trying to understand where is the place to reply and focus only on the Yammer webpart.

Comment: thanks for the reply and the info.. but i think you did not answer my actual question/concern?